# How to specify primary bean in grails 4 project

Tags: grails

I am trying to create a bean in Grails 4 and specify it as primary like we can do in Spring with the annotation

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Employee TonyEmployee() {
        return new Employee("Tony");
    }
```

How can we do with Grails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BeanBuilder DSL

i.e. to specify the primary dataSource

```
transactionManager(org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager) { bean ->
    dataSource = ref("dataSource")        
    bean.primary = true
}
```

https://docs.grails.org/4.0.1/guide/spring.html#theBeanBuilderDSLExplained

Comment: Thanks it works well.
I have also found another way to set it for existing beans, in `spring/resources.groovy`: springConfig.getBeanConfig("tonyEmployee").getBeanDefinition().setPrimary(true)